# Docker Node Alpine Image Build Fails on node-gyp

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, node-gyp, alpine-linux

I'm attempting to Dockerize a Vue.js application. I'm using the `node:10.15-alpine` Docker image as a base. The image build fails with the following error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/inotify
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! inotify@1.4.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the inotify@1.4.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The application runs on my Ubuntu machine. And I've searched for a resolution online.

I tried:

```
FROM node:10.15-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir -p /app/src
WORKDIR /app
COPY build/ config/ dist/ static/ .babelrc .postcssrc.js index.html /app/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc g++ python && \
  npm install --production --silent && \
  apk del make gcc g++ python
ADD src/ /app/src/
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This fails too. The error output is quite verbose and references C/C++ code.

Here's my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.15-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir -p /app/src
WORKDIR /app
COPY build/ config/ dist/ static/ .babelrc .postcssrc.js index.html /app/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
ADD src/ /app/src/
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue with node-gyp? I'd like to be able to run the application from with a Docker container, but I need to get the image to build first.

#### Update

Since the build was working on my Ubuntu machine, I checked the `node` version. It was 8.12, so I switch to using the `node:8.12-alpine` image and the application now works with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.12-alpine
RUN apk add g++ make python
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: This issue on GitHub might give some insight: [Document how to use alpine with dependencies that rely on node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/282)

Comment: Thanks @zero298 I did view that issue. I found a solution and updated my post. Cheers!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Also stated in my post update, here's the `Dockerfile` I used to get things working:

```
FROM node:8.12-alpine
RUN apk add g++ make py3-pip
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

If your requirements demand your image minimize space, consider installing necessary packages with `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual [package-list]` (instead of `apk add [package-list]`) and afterward clearing the cache in the image with `RUN apk del .gyp`.

Comment: It works for me too. The secret is in this command: `RUN apk add g++ make python`. Thanks

Comment: python package is not found. I had to use py3-pip instead

Comment: Yep, python package doesn't work anymore. Now you should use `RUN apk add g++ make py3-pip`

Comment: The @MGLondon answer which slims the container should be the new accepted answer, or this one should be updated

Comment: @KevinDanikowski, On the point of order you raise, the original question didn't mention anything about minimizing image size so not having that in the answer should be acceptable - I went ahead and added it on your suggestion though. My answer was here and accepted before @MGLondon's; I think it would have been more appropriate for that info to have been added as an edit to the accepted answer.

Comment: @Jason excellent point, I definitely agree

Comment: This helped me.  I had to add `USER root` before `RUN apk add g++ make py3-pip` to make it work.

Answer (score 27):

Since you are using an Alpine version on docker, you may want to use as little space as you can, while fixing the `node-gyp rebuild` error. For that it is recommended to use the below command i.e. without using a cache and with a virtual package which can be deleted later on.  Also you should combine the `apk add` and `npm install` commands together; this would help in further reducing space between docker cache layers.

```
FROM node:8.12-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
        python \
        make \
        g++ \
    && npm install \
    && apk del .gyp
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped reduced my image size by 72%.

Comment: It's simpler to user builder images instead of optimizing with package deletion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69477720/6618218
Problem i was facing and just added `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
        python \
        make \
        g++ \`

IT WORKED. Was it was issue to compilation to C++ at native level? Can you check error that i was facing on URL above was it due missing `g++, python thing`?
BTW, THANKS ALOT

Comment: I was using `FROM node:14.18-alpine` just curios will it work on full image like
FROM node:14` ? was it due alpine image? Sorry for NOOB questions :)

Answer (score 9):

For anyone using `node:14-alpine`, this fixed it for me: `RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip make g++`

Answer (score 8):

For anyone using `node:16.13-alpine3.15` (or close versions):

```
FROM node:16.13-alpine3.15

RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual .builds-deps build-base python3

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --production && npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source && npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Why is this specific for `node:16.13-alpine3.15`

Comment: Because i did not test it for another versions. But you can try!

Comment: May your enemies tremble at the sound of your name, thanks it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem by add **RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make** before **npm install**

```
# Stage 1, based on Node.js, to build and compile the react app
FROM node:12-alpine as build

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
COPY ./ /app/

#### => add this script to resolve that problem
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make

RUN npm install \
    && npm run build        
# Stage 2, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --update bash jq curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY --from=build /app/build/ /app/build

COPY ./scripts /app/scripts
COPY .env /app/scripts/.env
COPY ./nginx.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf.template

RUN chmod +x /app/scripts/getEnv.sh \
    && chmod +x /app/scripts/run.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/app/scripts/run.sh"]
```

Comment: This answer is probably out dated now (2023). Error: `/bin/sh: 1: apk: not found`,
`Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Answer (score 0):

I started having this problem when I went to Alpine 3.15 (I MAY have skipped 3.14; I can't remember). Instead of using a node base image, I'm using Microsoft.

It looks like in Alpine 3.13, the `npm` package was more aligned to the `nodejs` package. In Alpine 3.14, they changed `npm` to be the actual `npm` version. So, I added both `nodejs` and `npm` instead of **just** `npm` (line 2).

Here's my updated Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine AS publish
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs npm
WORKDIR /src

COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "MyWeb.csproj" -r linux-musl-x64
RUN dotnet publish "MyWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-musl-x64 --self-contained false --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs

ENTRYPOINT ["./MyWeb"]
```

NOTE: The `npm i` occurs as part of the build in the .csproj.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I started seeing this issue when upgrading from node v18.18.0 to v18.18.1. Fixed it by adding a `yarn global add node-gyp` before my `RUN yarn install` step:

```
from node:18.18-alpine

... copy deps, etc ...

RUN yarn global add node-gyp # <-- FIX HERE

RUN NODE_ENV=production yarn install --frozen-lockfile

... copy build app ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I try with Dockerfile here, it working

```
FROM arm64v8/node:18-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc g++ libc6-compat bash python3

RUN yarn global add node-gyp

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```